Why do some files show as Decompiled, SourceLink and Metadata?
I checked the Microsoft Symbols Server checkbox in Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols so I can view the source code.
Why is it that some files show decompiled while others show SourceLink?
For example Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.JwtBearerExtensions shows decompiled.
I noticed in the comment at the top of the file, it says Decompiled with ICsharpCode.Decompiler, does that have anything to do with it?

Whereas Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ControllerBase shows SourceLink:

Also, why does Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder only show metadata and not the actual sourcecode?


Source Link is a technology that enables source code debugging of .NET assemblies from NuGet by developers. However for those does not have enabled SourceLink VS can enable auto decompilation of the dll. The header Decompiled with ICsharpCode.Decompiler is an integration for ILSpy into Visual Studio.
You may refer to the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/decompilation?view=vs-2022#autodecompile-code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationBuilder should be available as sourcelink as it is open-sourced here:aspnetcore/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationBuilder.cs at main · dotnet/aspnetcore · GitHub.
